# Henry painted the house for four hours

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between these two sentences?

> Henry painted the house FOR four hours.

> Henry painted the house IN four hours.

Answer (score 2):

> Henry painted the house FOR four hours.

> Henry painted the house IN four hours.

The second example says the painting has been completed.

The first example does not say whether the painting has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

> Henry painted the house **for** four hours.

This sentence indicates how long Henry was painting and nothing more. We don't know if the painting was in progress when the four hours began, and we don't know if he finished the job. We also don't know if Henry managed the project, or if he was just a worker.

> Henry painted the house **in** four hours.

This sentence indicates that the total amount of time required to complete the job from start to finish was four hours. Furthermore, there is a suggestion that 4 hours was a pretty good time. You might say it in this context:

> Your husband took a whole day to paint your house? Henry painted ours in four hours. He's awesome.

We also know that Henry took all or most of the responsibility for getting the job done.